# How to chain together multiple NAudio ISampleProvider Effects

Tags: c#, naudio

I have some DSP effects coded in the ISampleProvider model. To apply one effect I do this and it works fine.

```
string filename = "C:\myaudio.mp3";
MediaFoundationReader mediaFileReader = new MediaFoundationReader(filename);
ISampleProvider sampProvider = mediaFileReader.ToSampleProvider();
ReverbSampleProvider reverbSamplr = new ReverbSampleProvider(sampProvider);
IWavePlayer waveOutDevice.Init(reverbSamplr);
waveOutDevice.Play();
```

How can I apply multiple effects to the same input file simultaneously?
For example, if i have a Reverb effect and Distortion effect providers, how can I chain them together to apply them at the same time to one input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effects can be chained together by passing one as the "source" for the next. So if you wanted your audio to go first through a reverb, and then distortion, you might do something like this, passing the original audio into the Reverb effect, the output of the reverb into the distortion effect and then sending the distortion to the waveOut device.

```
var reverb = new ReverbSampleProvider(sampProvider);
var distortion = new DistortionSampleProvider(reverb);
waveOutDevice.Init(distortion);
```

(n.b. NAudio does not come with built in reverb/distortion effects - you must make these yourself or source them from elsewhere)

Comment: Ha, so easy. It works Perfect. Thanks Mark, the ISampleProvider framework is Genius.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer is correct, but that approach is a pain if you're copy and pasting things around in different orders, because you have to change the variables that you're passing through.

For example, if you start with:

```
var lpf = new LowPassEffectStream(input);
var reverb = new ReverbEffectStream(lpf);
var stereo = new StereoEffectStream(reverb);
var vol = new VolumeSampleProvider(stereo);
waveOutDevice.Init(vol);
```

And you want to swap reverb and stereo, a quick copy-paste leaves you with the input variables backwards:

```
var lpf = new LowPassEffectStream(input);
var stereo = new StereoEffectStream(reverb); // <--
var reverb = new ReverbEffectStream(lpf);    // <--
var vol = new VolumeSampleProvider(stereo);
waveOutDevice.Init(vol);
```

It also makes it easy to fix a parameter but forget to fix another, e.g. fixing the `stereo` effect to have `lpf` as its input, but forgetting to fix the `reverb` effect. This often results in skipped effects in the chain leading to frustrated debugging when the effect appears not to work.

To make things easier and less error-prone when I'm stacking effects together and re-ordering them, I created the following helper class:

```
class EffectChain : ISampleProvider
{
    public EffectChain(ISampleProvider source)
    {
        this._sourceStream = source;
    }

    private readonly ISampleProvider _sourceStream;
    private readonly List<ISampleProvider> _chain = new List<ISampleProvider>();

    public ISampleProvider Head
    {
        get
        {
            return _chain.LastOrDefault() ?? _sourceStream;
        }
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return Head.WaveFormat;
        }
    }

    public void AddEffect(ISampleProvider effect)
    {
        _chain.Add(effect);
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return Head.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var effectChain = new EffectChain(input);

var lpf = new LowPassEffectStream(effectChain.Head);
effectChain.AddEffect(lpf);
var stereo = new StereoEffectStream(effectChain.Head);
effectChain.AddEffect(stereo);
var reverb = new ReverbEffectStream(effectChain.Head);
effectChain.AddEffect(reverb);
var vol = new VolumeSampleProvider(effectChain.Head);
effectChain.AddEffect(vol);

waveOutDevice.Init(effectChain);
```

This allows you to quickly re-order effects in the chain, as each effect takes the effect chain's head as an input. If you don't add any effects it just acts as a pass-through. You could easily expand this class to have more methods for managing the contained effects if you wanted to, but as it stands it works quite cleanly.